# ASPCOMPILER ERROR - Error al publicar proyecto ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Al momento de querer publicar un proyecto de ASP.net full framework, me genera este arhcivo temporal con el siguiente mensaje

```
System.AggregateException: Se han producido uno o varios errores. ---> System.Exception: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.
  --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
en Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__3()
en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
en Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel. <RunPublishTaskAsync>d__202.MoveNext()
---> (Nº de excepción interna 0) System.Exception: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.<---

System.Exception: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.
```

Sólo sucede cuando deseo publicar por medio del sistema de archivos en visual studio 2019, ya que si deseo compilar y debuggear el código, lo hace sin problemas en el navegador, incluso si antes de publicar, compilo el proyecto tambien me sale sin errores

también en la lista de errores, aparece esto
[image: error visual studio]

utilizo el framework 4.7.2 para el proyecto

Comment: Intenta ejecutar tu proyecto como Release, para ver si cuentas con el mismo error. A veces al ejecutarlo en modo Release se hace una compilación y linker más estricto, por lo que podrían suceder errores que en Debug no sucede, además de tomar la configuración de producción en caso de ser diferente a la de desarrollo

Comment: de hecho siempre lo ejecuto en modo release

Comment: Este error indica claramente que hay una excepción en alguna de las páginas. Ocurre que te lo indica, pero no te dice en qué página se encuentra el error. Me temo que deberás ir una a una y comprobar cuál de ellas es.

Comment: pero y porque menciona algo de APSNETCOMPILER?

Comment: No veo nada de ASPNETCOMPILER en la pila de errores que pusiste. Pero claramente pone "System.Exception: Error de compilación". Eso es que encuentra uno o varios errores en la aplicación en el momento de compilar. En ocasiones algo funciona y compila correctamente, cambias alguna función en otro lugar de la aplicación y deja de funcionar. El problema es que no te indica donde se produce el error.

Comment: No no menciona nada de eso y hace más dificil encontrar el error

Comment: además que en otras computadoras si se puede publicar

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿en qué carpeta estás desarrollando? Es probable que la longitud de la ruta sea demasiada extensa.

Comment: carpeta? o sea la carpeta de windows?